# Keychain whenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly after passcode reset wipes keychain value twice

Tags: keychain

Let's consider using KeychainAccess lib:

```
private let keychain = Keychain(service: "som.service.name")

func getProperty(_ prop: String) -> String? {
    return try? keychain
        .get(prop)
}

func setProperty(_ prop: String, value: String) {
    try? keychain
        .accessibility(.whenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly)
        .set(value, key: prop)
}
```

**Issue**:
When variable is stored in keychain with ".whenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly" flag,
it's expected to have it wiped once user removes device's passcode.
After setting new passcode, it should be possible to store and retrieve new value
but it appears that ofter first device-lock for at least 10 seconds, keychain item is wiped again.
**Repro steps**:
- device's passcode is set
- store / retrieve value (works fine)
- remove device's passcode (do not change - changing passcode doesn't affect keychain persistance)
- set device's passcode (do not lock the device, just run the app)
- try to retrieve old value -> value is wiped (that's expected)
- store / retrieve new value (works fine)
- lock device for at least 10 seconds
- try to retrieve stored value (ISSUE: value is wiped again)
- since now (after first 10-sec lock), keychain works normally, following device locks don't affect keychain persistance anymore

I need the keychain values to be retrievable always after passcode is set again on the device and app user stored new value.
Why it is wiped again after I lock the device for at least 10 seconds?
Any help, ideas, workarounds would be very appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the issue/osstatus/error you are getting when retrieving the stored value with the new stored item?

Comment: There is no error, the value is just nil. But I managed to workaround it adding authenticationPolicy:
```.accessibility(.whenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly, authenticationPolicy: .and)```
Not sure what exactly it does but it solves the issue.